# Z2 topological index: Is this unconventional formula summed over just filled bands, or all bands?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, berry-phase

The $\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological index is usually defined in terms of the Pfaffian of the overlap matrix, as defined [by eq. 4 of Kane and Mele's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0506581.pdf) paper:
$$
P(k)=\text{Pf}[\langle u_i(k) | \Theta | u_j(k) \rangle],
\tag{1}$$
where Pf is the Pfaffian and $\Theta$ is the time reversal operator.

However, [this review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09016.pdf) gives an alternative definition of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ index in Eq. 7 of the review, that seems rather unconventional:
$$\tag{2}
\mathbb{Z}_2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[ \oint_{\partial HBZ} A dk - \int_{HBZ} \Omega_z d^2k \right] (\text{mod } 2),
$$
where HBZ is the half-Brillouin zone, $A$ is the Berry connection and $\Omega$ is the Berry curvature.

**I am not sure how the unusual definition is used in practice (is it summed over filled bands? or all bands?)**. The reason I am asking is because the latter, unusual form seems easier to compute numerically (unless I missed some easier trick).

Comment: In the interest of saving space here, I moved the discussion here to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59886679#59886679)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.